# lmer logit regression - unexpected coefficients

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

I have a simulated dataset of `N` observations over `NGroup` individuals with a covariate `x1` and a binary response `y`. The data is generated from

$y_{i,j[i]} = \beta_{0,j[i]} + \beta_1 x_{i} + \epsilon_i,\ i\in\{1,\ldots,N\},\ j[i]\in\{1,\ldots,J\}$

where $J$ is the number of groups and $N$ is the population size.

This is the data set:

```
set.seed(1991)
N       <- 1000    # number of total observations
NGroups <- 2       # number of individuals
beta1   <- 3       # slope for entire population
beta01  <- -2      # intercept individual 1 
beta02  <- 2       # intercept individual 2

sigmoid = function(x) {
  1 / (1 + exp(-x))
}

# data
dt <- data.table(
        'x1' = rnorm(n = N, mean = 0, sd = 1),
        'group' = gl(n = NGroups, k = NGroups, length = N),
        'eps' = rnorm(n = N, mean = 0, sd = 0.5))
dt$y = 1*(sigmoid(beta1 * dt$x1 + dt$eps + ifelse(dt$group==1, beta01, beta02)) > 0.5)
```

To fit a logistic regression with mixed effects I am using

```
glmm <- glmer(y ~ -1 + x1 + (1 | group), data = dt, family=binomial(link = "logit"))

coef(glmm)$group
  (Intercept)       x1
1   -7.621388 11.37461
2    7.645489 11.37461
     ^--- expect something close to -2 and 2 here
               ^--- expect something close to 3 here
```

There is a large discrepancy between the true parameters `beta1`, `beta01,beta02` and the estimated parameters.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a piece of R code that simulates from the model you're looking for. You can adjust the parameters accordingly:

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 100 # number of subjects
K <- 8 # number of measurements per subject

# we constuct a data frame with the design: 
DF <- data.frame(id = rep(seq_len(n), each = K),
                 x = rep(rnorm(n), each = K))

# design matrices for the fixed and random effects
X <- model.matrix(~ x, data = DF)
Z <- model.matrix(~ 1, data = DF)

betas <- c(-2.13, 1) # fixed effects coefficients
D11 <- 1 # variance of random intercepts

# we simulate random effects
b <- cbind(rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D11)))
# linear predictor
eta_y <- drop(X %*% betas + rowSums(Z * b[DF$id, ]))
# we simulate binary data
DF$y <- rbinom(n * K, 1, plogis(eta_y))

# Fit the model
library("lme4")
fm <- glmer(y ~ x + (1 | id), data = DF, family = binomial())
fm
```

Comment: Cool answer! If we wanted to generate normal data instead, could we do something like this: DF$y <- rnorm(n * K, mean=eta_y, sd=sigma), where sigma is specified?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, indeed you just need to replace the definition of `DF$y`. Moreover, I've on purpose written it the random-effects part of the linear predictor as `rowSums(Z * b[DF$id, ])`, which is a bit of an overkill for a random intercept model (i.e., `b[DF$id]` would suffice), but this is more general, and it would work if you want to include more random effects (e.g., linear random slopes, quadratic random slopes, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, Dimitris! If we had a random slope as well, I am guessing b would be simulated from a bivariate normal distribution with something like mvnorm.

Comment: Yes, unless you want independent random effects, in which case you could still do it with `rnorm()`.